# How to get the index value corresponding to a max value for a specific column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset uber_data having columns as [START_DATE* ,END_DATE*    CATEGORY* , START* ,STOP* ,MILES* ]where START* is the starting location and STOP* is the ending location. I have to get the most frequent route taken by uber driver.

And below is the code that I m using to get the required.

**uber_data[['START*','STOP*','START_DATE*']].groupby(['START*','STOP*']).count().max()**

This is getting me the number of routes which comes to be 201. But I could not figure it how to get the combination for which this 201 is coming. I have to manually see through the data to know the combination which comes out to be Agnew-Cary

I want my output in this way

**START*    STOP*   START_DATE*

Agnew     Cary        201**

I tried getting the value using index() but did not get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
 uber_data.groupby(['START*','STOP*'])['START_DATE*'].count().sort_values(ascending=False).head(1)
```

which should give you both the index and value

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy . You guys are like life saviors for newbies like us. :)